# Rails Triple Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider three models. A user, an inventory and an inventory items one.

A user belongs to inventory. An inventory has one user. An inventory has many inventory items and an inventory item belongs to inventory. ( i know that a user has one inventory should probably be better, but i was less knowledgeable of ruby when doing my associations ).

Now, i was wondering what is the best way of, say, checking whether a user has a certain item in his inventory.

What do you think ? Maybe you would also suggest that i change my associations ? I'm open to criticism :)

Comment: Might be worth posting the actual code for your associations (not the rest of the models) just to make the associations absolutely clear. Gregor's answer below is good, but I don't think it'll work if you don't have a relationship from your user to your inventory. The solution in that case would be to fix your associations and then apply Gregor's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `:through => ...` option of `has_many`. For example:

```
class User ...
  has_many :inventory_items, :through => :inventories 

  ...
end
```

Then you can use `find` on the `inventory_items` collection of the user.

```
user = User.first
item = user.inventory_items.find(...)
```

For more informations see the rails api doc of `ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods`.